# Gmapping works in Gazebo, but not on robot

Tags: ros, navigation, youbot, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

another problem with gmapping.

When using the Gazebo simulator gmapping works fine with this command

```
$ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=youbot/scan_front _base_frame:=youbot/base_link _odom_frame:=youbot/odom
```

As far as I understand this correcly, the arguments should be

- `scan:=scan`
- `_base_link:=base_link`
- `_odom_frame:=odom`

which are the default values, so just starting it with `$ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan` should work. The values were obtained from a `rosrun tf view_frames` (image is a link, click to expand) and `rostopic list`.

[image: image description]

```
$ rostopic list
/cmd_vel
/cmd_vel_safe
/dashboard/platform_state
/diagnostics
/hokuyo_node/parameter_descriptions
/hokuyo_node/parameter_updates
/joint_states
/map
/map_metadata
/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/scan
/slam_gmapping/entropy
/tf
/tf_static
```

Gmapping gives with the error:

```
 [ WARN] [1444300130.237434289]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.gmapping.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

which then leads me to the debug messages:

```
[DEBUG] [1444300178.106273471]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Added message in frame laser at time 1444300192.911, count now 5
[DEBUG] [1444300178.210528915]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Removed oldest message because buffer is full, count now 5 (frame_id=laser, stamp=1444300192.508830)
```

In Gazebo Gmapping starts up with some messages (Laser pose, values of settings,...) until `Registering first Scan` appears, on the actual robot there is just the warning message after a time.

I really don't know what the problem is and would be glad about any input!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218849/gmapping-works-in-gazebo,-but-not-on-robot/) by [85pando](https://answers.ros.org/users/23227/85pando/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure but on attached log I saw:

```
frame_id=laser
```

but this frame does not appear in your tf tree. I guess this is the frame id set on your scan messages but since it does not exists...

---

Originally posted by [afranceson](https://answers.ros.org/users/19838/afranceson/) with karma: 497 on 2015-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [85pando](https://answers.ros.org/users/23227/85pando/) on 2015-10-14**:
Yeah, that helped a lot. The Hokuyo node publishes on the wrong frame. For the youbot I now changed the launch file to include:

```
<node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo_node">
  <param name="frame_id" value="/base_laser_front_link" />
</node>
```